# Cannot load jQuery-ui on Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dreamweaver

I am new to jQuery, and even newer to Dreamweaver CC.  I am trying to use the animated version of `toggleClass` that is available to jQuery-ui, but I cannot load jQuery ui for some reason.  Dreamweaver already has some jQuery elements which might be interfering, but I cannot be sure.

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Stargazer</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css">
<!--    <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
  <!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
  <script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/caesar-dressing:n4:default;lobster-two:n4:default;chicle:n4:default;henny-penny:n4:default;immi-five-o-five:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jQueryAssets/testing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

The last 2 lines are where I attempt to load jQuery-ui as well as my custom sheet where I write all my jQuery.  When I attempt to test if jQuery is loading using `if (jQuery-ui) {alert('loaded')}` I receive no alert.

I have tried several similar loading methods but nothing seems to work.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: dreamweaver will do nothing but cause headaches - opinion

Comment: Do you have the jquery UI in the specified folder?

Comment: @iam-decoder I didn't know people still _used_ Dreamweaver. Weave your own dreams! Take a notepad and start typing. In constrast, Dreamweaver is like taking a piece of cloth, pulling it apart, then stitching it back together and calling it your own.

Comment: To know if your page is loading jquery-ui file, open the page on your browser (preferably Chrome) and check the Network tab where you can see if the GET request has been made on said file.

Comment: Dreamweaver was available as free software at work, so I have been playing around with it, thats the only reason why

Comment: @JeremyThomas I'd suggest looking into Sublime Text and/or an IDE

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your test in a doc ready function"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if (jQuery-ui) {
     alert('loaded')
  }
});
```

Or try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ui.version
});
```

Comment: Check my revision, if it does not work, check to see what is being logged in your console (F12)... I would expect to see something like $ is not defined